# Recommendations for a scoring formula for sorting a location based social network's post feed

Tags: algorithm, sorting, formula

I'm building a location based social networking app. The idea is to allow users to post and interact with people nearby. The main feed of the app would show posts based on their proximity (d = how far the post was posted) and recency (a = how long ago was it posted).

I am trying to come up with a formula which would score each post for sorting and achieve the following objectives:

- High recency and high proximity posts show first (e.g d=1km, a=1 hour)
- If a post is high proximity but quite old (e.g. d=1km, a=5 days), slightly further results (e.g. d=5km, a=1 hour) rank higher
- Very far off posts (e.g. d=10000, a=1 hour) would only rank higher than nearby posts which are extremely old (e.g. d=10km, a=1 year)

**We are trying to strike a balance between seeing things which are local enough too be relevant yet fresh.** While algorithmic solutions are possible, at this point we are looking for a formula to score and sort posts. Looking for suggestions for suitable scoring formulas.

Answer (score 0):

A good formula will almost certainly have some arbitrary parameters that require tweaking. (To see why, observe that you'd want the same result whether the distance is denominated in meters, where 500 is a pretty small value, or kilometers, where 500 is a pretty big value.)

For medium-to-large values, my hunch is that you'll want a logarithmic scale; the difference between 1 km and 2 km seems pretty similar to the difference between between 100 km and 200 km (rather than to the difference between 100 km and 101 km), and the difference between 3 days and 6 days seems pretty similar to the difference between 30 days and 60 days (rather than to the difference between 30 days and 31 days). That means something like

> score = *a* log *d* + *b* log *t*

(where a lower score means the post is more relevant).

However, because logarithms diverge to negative infinity for extremely small values, you'd need to adjust this for really small values; you don't want "right here, a year ago" and "other side of the Earth, zero seconds ago" to be deemed more relevant than "thirty meters away, ten minutes ago". One way is to add a bit of an offset so that you don't take logarithms of very small values:

> score = *a* log(*d*+1) + *b* log(*t*+1)

I'm sure you'll find you have to do more tweaking over time. I'll be interested to hear what you come up with!